# Clientscript.RegisterStartupScript not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a website in which I am trying to display messages through ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript.

This one was displayed successfully:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", 
  "alert('All questions have been visited !');", true);
```

Although it gave a message with a checkbox saying "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs".I did not check the checkbox. In my code behind I have this condition:

```
if (lblUnConfirmedQuestions.Text=="0")
{
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "msg", 
     "alert( 'Please attempt all the questions !')",true);         
}
```

This one was supposed to be displayed later but it did not appear.

On the internet I found a suggestion to remove single quotes from the ClientScript message ,I removed them but still no success could be achieved.What should I do to display the second clientscript message?

Comment: Why are you using RegisterStartupScript to display popups. Instead, this should be used to load a generic library and then you call a method in that library from your code.

Answer (score 1):

`"Please attempt all the questions !"` is just text.

You need something like this in order to display alert message.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
    "msg", "alert('Please attempt all the questions !');",true);
```

Comment: Sorry! That was an editing mistake from my side.I have corrected it now.I actually used alert as well.

Comment: @TVicky Set a break point at **if statement**, and debug it. Other than that, your code should be working. If you use Ajax, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20149916/296861).

Comment: @TVicky Your updated codes is working fine. However, if there is a Javascript error in other code, above code will stop working too. ***How to debug*** : create an ASPX page without Master Page, copy the above code, and debug it.